# i already installed 32-bit python 3.9 in win 10 i downloaded it from the python page when installing the matplotlib libary use pip install matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, installation

Matplotlib library was not installed

use pip install matplotlib and it didn't work update pip command and i got the same error
....\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Could not find C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe

```
  A full log can be found at C:\Users\amine\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-covljw6j\contourpy_fd214a1f6aad48e49c38106dc5541be3\.mesonpy-98i2a9oq\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer but there is no 32-bit version of anaconda, after several tests i discovered that there is a bug matplotlib in 32-bit platform only works with python 3.7 32-bit, although on the python website the latest python version is 3.11 this does not work with matplotlib only works with version 3.7 of python thanks